# Access HTTP nested JSON data in Angular

Tags: json, angular

Here's the component in question:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  {{tests | json}}

    <div *ngFor='let test of tests'>
        <div *ngFor='let x of test.A.B'>
          <div *ngFor='let y of x.C.D'>
            writerid:{{y.writerid}} <br>
            content:{{y.content}} <br>
            writedt:{{y.writedt }} <br>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  `,
})

public tests: any[];
```

The constructor gets the JSON data from an API here:

```
constructor(private _http: Http) {
    _http.get(this.API_URI).subscribe(result => {
      this.tests = result.json();
    });
  }
```

This is my JSON data from `http(API_URI)`, printed by `{{tests | json}}` (in @component, template):

```
 {
   'A': {
     'B': [{
       'C': {
         'D': [{
           'content': 'content_test1',
           'writedt': '2017-02-08 00:00:00',
           'writerid': 'writerid_test1'
          }, {
           'content': 'content_test2',
           'writedt': '2017-02-08 00:00:00',
           'writerid': 'writerid_test1'
          }, {
            'content': 'content_test3',
            'writedt': '2017-02-08 00:00:00',
            'writerid': 'writerid_test2'
          },  {
           'content': 'content_test4',
           'writedt': '2017-02-08 00:00:00',
           'writerid': 'writerid_test2'
         }]
       }
     }]
   }
 }
```

The error I get is this:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Let's start with the blatant:  `tests` in JSON format is a JSON *object*, not a JSON *array*, which is why you can't iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your json, it has object but ngFor works for array types

```
<div *ngFor='let x of tests.A.B'>
          <div *ngFor='let y of x.C.D'>
            writerid:{{y.writerid}} <br>
            content:{{y.content}} <br>
            writedt:{{y.writedt }} <br>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

That is the reason you get this error.

**Mistakes**

1. `<div *ngFor='let test of tests'>` - tests is of type object and not a collection of objects or array.

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/eAA9FpMqLf9bJywRRakn?p=preview)

Comment: it works in local json data but when i get data from http like

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    _http.get(this.API_URI).subscribe(result => {
      this.tests = result.json();
    });
  }

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_source' of undefined

Comment: can you use my demo plunker and create it for http call with json file

Comment: this is my real json data it still doesn't work TT
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hits' of undefined

Comment: {
 "hits": {
  "hits": [{
   "_source": {
    "json_comments": [{
     "content": "\u314b\u314b\u314b\u314b - DCW",
     "writedt": "2016-02-08 17:05:48",
     "writerid": "morefico3042"
    }, {
     "content": "\uc800\ubc88\uc5d0 \ub3d9\uc7a5A\uc758 \ubcbd\uc744 \uc2e4\uac10\ud558\uc2dc\uace0\ub3c4 \ub3c4\uc804\ud558\uc2dc\ub294? \u3161\u3161",
     "writedt": "2016-02-08 17:07:38",
     "writerid": "\uce74\ub77c\ube71"
    }]
   }
  }]
 }
}